# Vue display an image from firebase cloud storage blob

Tags: javascript, html, image, vue.js, vuejs2

Im building a product lookup repository, users will scan a product barcode which will then return data about the product and a picture of the product to be displayed.

Right now for testing purposes I have set up a firebase storage bucket, with one image uploaded. Im have successfully been able to retrieve the image by calling the firebase storage api, but I cant seem to display it in my Vue app. I cant seem to find the proper documentation for this on firebase docs, as their example uses plain js and html.

My code to display the image:

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <image v-if="image!==null" :src="image"></image>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

The script that runs when the page is mounted and it will get the image from the storage bucket and display it.

```
<script>
import firebase from "firebase";
export default {
  name: "ProductPage",
  data: () => {
    return {
      image: null
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    firebase
      .storage()
      .ref("test/1234-1.jpg")
      .getDownloadURL()
      .then(url => {
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.responseType = "blob";
        xhr.onload = event => {
          this.image = xhr.response;
          event.preventDefault();
        };
        xhr.open("GET", url);
        xhr.send();
      })
      .catch(error => {
        // Handle any errors
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
};
</script>
```

I know the api call works because when I check the developer console in chrome, i can see the image in preview on the api call in the networks tab. I just cant seem to display it in vue.

It stores the image as blob?

[image]

I have added the responses as requested:
[image]

Comment: Can you add the response from your Dev Console?

Comment: its a blob, the response tab has nothing, but the preview tab shows the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies not in the blob, but the vue tag to display the image. Instead of `<image>` we use `<img>` like this:

```
<img v-if="image !== null" :src="image" class="img-circle" alt="Services">
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be with Vue displaying Blob. Try:

```js
xhr.onload = event => {
  this.image = URL.createObjectURL(xhr.response);
  event.preventDefault();
};
```

Here the `URL.createObjectURL` should create a reference to the Blob.

Comment: Still showing nothing, no errors or anything. just nothing being shown.

Comment: So now if i check what vue is storing the image as, its still a blob:
"blob:http://localhost:8080/2fb0f4eb....